# Target UI Thread Control for threadsafe calls

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm researching threadsafe calls and it's quite difficult. I've a method that helps me add a new tab to a tabcontrol, but I want to invoke this from a thread that the UI is not associated with.

My current tab creation code looks like this. It is not threadsafe.

```
 TabPage tpage = new TabPage();
 tpage.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;

 //tabcontrol_borwser is the name of the tabcontrol on my ui
 tabcontrol_browser.TabPages.Insert(tabcontrol_browser.TabCount, tpage);
```

How would I do this from a separate thread that allowed me to target the same control by name that exists on the primary UI thread?

I'd like to stay away from creating thread safe wrapper classes for each control as I would have to do this for every UI control I've created and what a hassle!

The easiest logical way to do it is to create a nameholder that works like this:

```
PrimaryThread.Control.tabcontrol_browser.TabPages.Insert(tabcontrol_browser.TabCount, tpage);
```

Is there a way for me to do it this way?

Here is the whole method used to create a tab:

```
    private String f_create_new_tab(string tab_name)
    {
        // create a new TabPage object
        tabcontrol_browser.Invoke( () => {
            TabPage tpage = new TabPage();
            tpage.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;


            //add the newly created TabPage
            //to the tabcontrol's collection of tab pages 
            tabcontrol_browser.TabPages.Insert(tabcontrol_browser.TabCount, tpage);
            int count = tabcontrol_browser.TabCount;
            tab_name = count.ToString() + ") " +tab_name;
            tpage.Text = tab_name;
            tpage.Name = tab_name;

            //create a WebBrowser object
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.Name = "browser_" + tab_name;
            browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
            WaitBrowserLoading();
            //add the browser object to the tab page 
            //you created previously
            tpage.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tabcontrol_browser.SelectTab(tpage);

            //add some event handlers to your browser object
            browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(f_browser_pagechange);
            string browsername = "browser_" + tab_name;
            return browsername;
        });
    }
```

Comment: if you have to make it thread safe you have to serialize access to tabcontrol_browser from everywhere you are using or you only want to thread safe tabcontrol_browser.TabPages.Insert() call?

Comment: I can assign/synchronize the rights for threads to use my main threads UI by serializing access?

Comment: only the UI thread can work on controls. So if you are calling Insert method on tabcontrol_browser you have to call Invoke if the current thread is not your main thread. I still dont understand what you really want, you want to serialize access to tabcontrol_browser functions or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help you, but anytime I try to call back to the UI thread to post something or do anything to the UI I use this extension method:

```
   public static class ControlExtensions
   {
      public static void Invoke(this Control Control, Action Action)
      {
         Control.Invoke(Action);
      }
   }
```

this would be the use of it for your case:

```
   if(tabcontrol_browser.InvokeRequired())
   {     
      tabcontrol.Invoke( () => {
                                 TabPage tpage = new TabPage();
                                 tpage.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                                 tabcontrol_browser.TabPages.Insert(tabcontrol_browser.TabCount, tpage)
                               });
   }
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show the whole method. But I'm getting this error on the Invoke line. ""Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type""